# Can i remove Pagination from external site with cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion

I am fetching one website results in my website and if there are any much more records, the pagination is also coming along with it, so it is displaying pagination and records

this is more than a question rather than before i make any try and i do not know where to start

is this possible, can i make infinite pagination of the results through some client side or server side, let me know please thanks

Pagination look like this in the `cfhttp.filecontent` as:

```
<TD align="right" width="100"><font class="MainBody">Pages:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://websiteaddress.com/9.asp?type=10&pagenum=1"><<</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;<a href="http://websiteaddress.com/9.asp?type=10&pagenum=2">2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://websiteaddress.com/9.asp?type=10&pagenum=2">>></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
```

Comment: Yes this is possible. But not a great question JoJo. You should try some things first and paste some code with some specific problems. You should have no problem googling "pagination examples coldfusion".

Comment: Ah... I see you are "fetching" these records via HTTP. Perhaps you could post your code.

Comment: Hard to post code when you don't know when to start.  I don't use cfhttp much in my line of work but this does sound like a difficult endeavour.

Comment: @Dan: Yes you are right, i do not know how to start it, I am using cfhttp

Comment: Post some code of what the returned pagination looks like. The answer to this is probably using a Regular Expression to parse it right out of `#cfhttp.filecontent#`

Comment: I am editing my main questions here @cfqueryparam

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. It searches for a TD tag followed by a FONT tag, followed by Pages.. and then searches to the first closing TD.

The result is stored in newfilecontent.

```
<cfset newfilecontent = REReplaceNoCase(cfhttp.filecontent,"<td.*?><font.*?>Pages.*?<\/td>","","ALL")>
```

With a more detailed question, what you need is basically a rudimentary spider.

This is only designed to work from the first page of results onward. You can't target this at say, page 3, and get page 2 and page 1's.

```
<cfhttp...> <!--- initial cfhttp --->
<cfset buildContents = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset buildContents[1] = ReReplaceNoCase(cfHttp.fileContent,".*<body.*?>(.*)</body>.*","\1","ALL")>
<!--- Quick regex to parse the contents of the body tag out of the cfhttp --->
<cfloop condition="#ReFindNoCase("(http[^""]*?pagenum=\d+)(?="">>>)",currentContent)# gt 0">
    <cfset GetNextPage = ReMatchNoCase("(http[^""]*?pagenum=\d+)(?="">>>)",currentContents)>
    <cfhttp url="#GetNextPage[1]#"... result="inLoop">
    <cfset currentContents = ReReplaceNoCase(inLoop.filecontent,".*<body.*?>(.*)</body>.*","\1","ALL")>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(buildContents,REReplaceNoCase(currentContents,"<td.*?><font.*?>Pages.*?<\/td>","","ALL"))>
    <cfif ArrayLen(buildContents) gt 10>
      <!--- This code is untested, so this is a safety that you can remove or modify. If BuildContents has more than ten elements, it stops the looping. You can remove this cfif or maybe raise the number as a safety net.--->
      <cfbreak>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#buildContents#">
```

Comment: and how i am gonna use it, as i told in my question, i am lost at this point, how do i do it, like after a first cfhttp call, make another cfhttp call, like that, i am seriously lost or if jquery is an option i am willing to do in jquery too,

Comment: Are you trying to get all the results on one page or just remove the pagination links?

Comment: i am getting the whole page in a container and that coming page from otehr sit has pagination too, so my initial thought of removing pagination and make it like infinite scroll because i do not have control over that page.. but if use jquery infinite scroll, i am lost where to start it and how to trigger it